# Validate XML using XSD, a Catalog Resolver, and JAXP DOM for XSLT

Tags: java, xml, validation, xslt, xsd

## Background

Using JDK 6 to load XML files into [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html). The XML files must be validated against an XSD. The XSD file location differs depending on the running environment. Ensuring the XML can be validated against an XSD, regardless of directory structure, requires a catalog resolver. Once the XML is validated, it can then be transformed.

My understanding is that a [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html) can be used to configure such validation. This is achieved by using a [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) with an [XMLCatalogResolver](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xerces2/org/apache/xerces/util/XMLCatalogResolver.html) to find the XSD file (and any included files) associated with an XML file.

Questions about validating XML documents using a catalog-derived XSD, include:

- [JAXP - debug XSD catalog look up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632422/jaxp-debug-xsd-catalog-look-up)
- [Java XML Schema validator with custom resource resolver fails to resolve elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538071/java-xml-schema-validator-with-custom-resource-resolver-fails-to-resolve-element)
- [Can XMLCatalog be used for schema imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981382/can-xmlcatalog-be-used-for-schema-imports)
- [How to load XMLCatalog from classpath resources (inside a jar), reliably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412798/)
- [XMLSchema validation with Catalog.xml file for entity resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364840/xmlschema-validation-with-catalog-xml-file-for-entity-resolving)
- [Resolving type definitions from imported schema in XJC fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982740/resolving-type-definitions-from-imported-schema-in-xjc-fails)
- [Find items that can be repeated in an xml schema using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471066/find-items-that-can-be-repeated-in-an-xml-schema-using-java)
- [Java servlets: xml validation against xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579837/java-servlets-xml-validation-against-xsd)

Most of these questions and answers reference a hard-coded XSD file path, or use [SAX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html) to perform the validation, or pertain to [DTDs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-mxd3/index.html), or require [JDOM dependencies](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html), or have no [transformation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html).

## Problem

There is no canonical solution that describes how to employ an XML catalog for XSD validation using JAXP DOM, that is subsequently transformed via XSLT. There are a [number](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-dom.html) of [snippets](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1378), but no complete, standalone example that compiles and runs (under JDK 6).

I posted an answer that seems to work, technically, but is overly verbose.

## Question

What is the canonical way (using JDK 1.6 libraries) to validate and transform an XML document? Here is one possible algorithm:

1. Create a catalog resolver.
2. Create an XML parser.
3. Associate the resolver with the parser.
4. Parse an XML document containing an XSD reference.
5. Terminate on validation errors.
6. Transform the validated XML using an XSL template.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Source Files

The source files include a catalog manager properties file, Java source code, catalog file, XML data, XSL files, and XSD files. All files are relative to the current working directory (`./`).

### Catalog Manager Properties File

This properties file is read by the CatalogResolver class; save as `./CatalogManager.properties`:

```
catalogs=catalog.xml
relative-catalogs=yes
verbosity=99
prefer=system
static-catalog=yes
allow-oasis-xml-catalog-pi=yes
```

### TestXSD.java

This is the main application; save it as `./src/TestXSD.java`:

```
package src;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

import org.apache.xml.resolver.tools.CatalogResolver;
import org.apache.xerces.util.XMLCatalogResolver;
import static org.apache.xerces.jaxp.JAXPConstants.JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE;
import static org.apache.xerces.jaxp.JAXPConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA;

import javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory;
import javax.xml.validation.Schema;
import javax.xml.validation.Validator;

import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;

import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;

import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

/**
 * Download http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/CatalogManager.properties
 */
public class TestXSD {
  private final static String ENTITY_RESOLVER =
    "http://apache.org/xml/properties/internal/entity-resolver";

  /**
   * This program reads an XML file, performs validation, reads an XSL
   * file, transforms the input XML, and then writes the transformed document
   * to standard output.
   *
   * args[0] - The XSL file used to transform the XML file
   * args[1] - The XML file to transform using the XSL file
   */
  public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    // For validation error messages.
    ErrorHandler errorHandler = new DocumentErrorHandler(); 

    // Read the CatalogManager.properties file.
    CatalogResolver resolver = new CatalogResolver();
    XMLCatalogResolver xmlResolver = createXMLCatalogResolver( resolver );

    logDebug( "READ XML INPUT SOURCE" );
    // Load an XML document in preparation to transform it.
    InputSource xmlInput = new InputSource( new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream( args[1] ) ) );

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setAttribute( JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA );
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware( true );

    DocumentBuilder builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    builder.setEntityResolver( xmlResolver );
    builder.setErrorHandler( errorHandler );

    logDebug( "PARSE XML INTO DOCUMENT MODEL" );
    Document xmlDocument = builder.parse( xmlInput );

    logDebug( "CONVERT XML DOCUMENT MODEL INTO DOMSOURCE" );
    DOMSource xml = new DOMSource( xmlDocument );

    logDebug( "GET XML SCHEMA DEFINITION" );
    String schemaURI = getSchemaURI( xmlDocument );

    logDebug( "SCHEMA URI: " + schemaURI );

    if( schemaURI != null ) {
      logDebug( "CREATE SCHEMA FACTORY" );
      // Create a Schema factory to obtain a Schema for XML validation...
      SchemaFactory sFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance( W3C_XML_SCHEMA );
      sFactory.setResourceResolver( xmlResolver );

      logDebug( "CREATE XSD INPUT SOURCE" );
      String xsdFileURI = xmlResolver.resolveURI( schemaURI );

      logDebug( "CREATE INPUT SOURCE XSD FROM: " + xsdFileURI );
      InputSource xsd = new InputSource(
        new FileInputStream( new File( new URI( xsdFileURI ) ) ) );

      logDebug( "CREATE SCHEMA OBJECT FOR XSD" );
      Schema schema = sFactory.newSchema( new SAXSource( xsd ) );

      logDebug( "CREATE VALIDATOR FOR SCHEMA" );
      Validator validator = schema.newValidator();

      logDebug( "VALIDATE XML AGAINST XSD" );
      validator.validate( xml );
    }

    logDebug( "READ XSL INPUT SOURCE" );
    // Load an XSL template for transforming XML documents.
    InputSource xslInput = new InputSource( new InputStreamReader(
      new FileInputStream( args[0] ) ) );

    logDebug( "PARSE XSL INTO DOCUMENT MODEL" );
    Document xslDocument = builder.parse( xslInput );

    transform( xmlDocument, xslDocument, resolver );
    System.out.println();
  }

  private static void transform(
    Document xml, Document xsl, CatalogResolver resolver ) throws Exception
  {
    if( versionAtLeast( xsl, 2 ) ) {
      useXSLT2Transformer();
    }

    logDebug( "CREATE TRANSFORMER FACTORY" );
    // Create the transformer used for the document.
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    tFactory.setURIResolver( resolver );

    logDebug( "CREATE TRANSFORMER FROM XSL" );
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer( new DOMSource( xsl ) );

    logDebug( "CREATE RESULT OUTPUT STREAM" );
    // This enables writing the results to standard output.
    Result out = new StreamResult( new OutputStreamWriter( System.out ) );

    logDebug( "TRANSFORM THE XML AND WRITE TO STDOUT" );
    // Transform the document using a given stylesheet.
    transformer.transform( new DOMSource( xml ), out );
  }

  /**
   * Answers whether the given XSL document version is greater than or
   * equal to the given required version number.
   *
   * @param xsl The XSL document to check for version compatibility.
   * @param version The version number to compare against.
   *
   * @return true iff the XSL document version is greater than or equal
   * to the version parameter.
   */
  private static boolean versionAtLeast( Document xsl, float version ) {
    Element root = xsl.getDocumentElement();
    float docVersion = Float.parseFloat( root.getAttribute( "version" ) );

    return docVersion >= version;
  }

  /**
   * Enables Saxon9's XSLT2 transformer for XSLT2 files.
   */
  private static void useXSLT2Transformer() {
    System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
      "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
  }

  /**
   * Creates an XMLCatalogResolver based on the file names found in
   * the given CatalogResolver. The resulting XMLCatalogResolver will
   * contain the absolute path to all the files known to the given
   * CatalogResolver.
   *
   * @param resolver The CatalogResolver to examine for catalog file names.
   * @return An XMLCatalogResolver instance with the same number of catalog
   * files as found in the given CatalogResolver.
   */
  private static XMLCatalogResolver createXMLCatalogResolver(
    CatalogResolver resolver ) {
    int index = 0;
    List files = resolver.getCatalog().getCatalogManager().getCatalogFiles();
    String catalogs[] = new String[ files.size() ];
    XMLCatalogResolver xmlResolver = new XMLCatalogResolver();

    for( Object file : files ) {
      catalogs[ index ] = (new File( file.toString() )).getAbsolutePath();
      index++;
    }

    xmlResolver.setCatalogList( catalogs );

    return xmlResolver;
  }

  private static String[] parseNameValue( String nv ) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\s*(\\w+)=\"([^\"]*)\"\\s*" );
    Matcher m = p.matcher( nv );
    String result[] = new String[2];

    if( m.find() ) {
      result[0] = m.group(1);
      result[1] = m.group(2);
    }

    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the XML schema definition using an XSD.
   *
   * @param node The document (or child node) to traverse seeking processing
   * instruction nodes.
   * @return null if no XSD is present in the XML document.
   * @throws IOException Never thrown (uses StringReader).
   */
  private static String getSchemaURI( Node node ) throws IOException {
    String result = null;

    if( node.getNodeType() == Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE ) {
      ProcessingInstruction pi = (ProcessingInstruction)node;

      logDebug( "NODE IS PROCESSING INSTRUCTION" );

      if( "xml-model".equals( pi.getNodeName() ) ) {
        logDebug( "PI IS XML MODEL" );

        // Hack to get the attributes.
        String data = pi.getData();

        if( data != null ) {
          final String attributes[] = pi.getData().trim().split( "\\s+" );

          String type = parseNameValue( attributes[0] )[1];
          String href = parseNameValue( attributes[1] )[1];

          // TODO: Schema should = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
          //String schema = attributes.getNamedItem( "schematypens" );

          if( "application/xml".equalsIgnoreCase( type ) && href != null ) {
            result = href;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      // Try to get the schema type information.
      NamedNodeMap attrs = node.getAttributes();

      if( attrs != null ) {
        // TypeInfo.toString() returns values of the form:
        // schemaLocation="uri schemaURI"
        // The following loop extracts the schema URI.
        for( int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); i++ ) {
          Attr attribute = (Attr)attrs.item( i );
          TypeInfo typeInfo = attribute.getSchemaTypeInfo();
          String attr[] = parseNameValue( typeInfo.toString() );

          if( "schemaLocation".equalsIgnoreCase( attr[0] ) ) {
            result = attr[1].split( "\\s" )[1];
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      // Look deeper for the schema URI.
      if( result == null ) {
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();

        for( int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++ ) {
          result = getSchemaURI( list.item( i ) );

          if( result != null ) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return result;
  }

  /**
   * Writes a message to standard output.
   */
  private static void logDebug( String s ) {
    System.out.println( s );
  }
}
```

### Error Handler

This is the code for human-friendly error messages; save as `./src/DocumentErrorHandler.java`:

```
package src;

import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

/**
 * Handles error messages during parsing and validating XML documents.
 */
public class DocumentErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  private final static PrintStream OUTSTREAM = System.err;

  private void log( String type, SAXParseException e ) {
    OUTSTREAM.println( "SAX PARSE EXCEPTION " + type );
    OUTSTREAM.println( "  Public ID: " + e.getPublicId() );
    OUTSTREAM.println( "  System ID: " + e.getSystemId() );
    OUTSTREAM.println( "  Line     : " + e.getLineNumber() );
    OUTSTREAM.println( "  Column   : " + e.getColumnNumber() );
    OUTSTREAM.println( "  Message  : " + e.getMessage() );
  }

  @Override
  public void error( SAXParseException e ) throws SAXException {
    log( "ERROR", e );
  }

  @Override
  public void fatalError( SAXParseException e ) throws SAXException {
    log( "FATAL ERROR", e );
  }

  @Override
  public void warning( SAXParseException e ) throws SAXException {
    log( "WARNING", e );
  }
}
```

### Catalog File

Save as `./catalog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XML Catalogs V1.1//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.1/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <!-- XSDs linked through primary catalog -->
    <!-- catalog entry for good-note1.xml -->
    <rewriteSystem 
        systemIdStartString="http://stackoverflow.com/schema" 
        rewritePrefix="./ArbitraryFolder/schemas"
    />

    <!-- catalog entry for good-note2.xml, good-note3.xml, bad-note1.xml, bad-note2.xml -->
    <rewriteURI 
        uriStartString="http://stackoverflow.com/2014/09/xsd" 
        rewritePrefix="./ArbitraryFolder/schemas"
    />

    <!-- add a second catalog as a further test:
         XSL will be resolved through it -->
    <nextCatalog 
        catalog="./ArbitraryFolder/catalog.xml"
    />
</catalog>
```

### XML Data

The different test cases include XSDs referenced in either processing instructions or root nodes.

#### Schema: Processing Instruction

The schema can be provided using an `xml-model` processing instruction (PI). Save as `./Tests/good-notes2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Associating Schemas with XML documents: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-model/ -->
<?xml-model type="application/xml" href="http://stackoverflow.com/2014/09/xsd/notes/notes.xsd"?>
<note>
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <date>2014-08-30</date>
    <body>headlight fluid, flamgrabblit, exhaust coil</body>
</note>
```

#### Schema: Root Node

The schema can be provided in attributes of the document's root node. Save as `./Tests/good-notes3.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- XML Schema Part 1: Structures: 
     Schema-Related Markup in Documents Being Validated: 
     http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions -->
<note 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://stackoverflow.com http://stackoverflow.com/2014/09/xsd/notes/notes.xsd">
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <date>2014-08-30</date>
    <body>Eggs, Milk, Carrots</body>
</note>
```

#### Fail Validation

The following should fail validation (date needs hyphens); save as `./Tests/bad-note1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Associating Schemas with XML documents: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-model/ -->
<?xml-model type="application/xml" href="http://stackoverflow.com/2014/09/xsd/notes/notes.xsd"?>
<!-- FAILS SCHEMA: date is not valid; should use hyphens -->
<note>
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <date>20140830</date>
    <body>headlight fluid, flamgrabblit, exhaust coil</body>
</note>
```

## Transformation

Save this as `./Tests/note-to-html.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- is in the second catalog (../ArbitraryFolder/catalog.xml) -->
    <xsl:import href="http://stackoverflow.com/2014/09/xsl/notes/notes.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Arbitrary Folder

The arbitrary folder represents the path to files on a computer that can be located anywhere on the file system. The location of these files could differ, for example, between production, development, and the repository.

### Catalog

Save this file as `./ArbitraryFolder/catalog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XML Catalogs V1.1//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.1/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">

    <!-- catalog entry for all notes -->
    <rewriteURI 
        uriStartString="http://stackoverflow.com/2014/09/xsl/" 
        rewritePrefix="./XSL/"/>

</catalog>
```

### Notes

There are two files in this example for transforming the notes: notes.xsl and note-body.xsl. The first includes the second.

#### Notes Stylesheet

Save this as `./ArbitraryFolder/XSL/notes/notes.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <!-- will not be in catalog (though it could be): 
         by convention, absolute path is assumed to be part of static file structure -->
    <xsl:import href="note-body.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>A Note</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="note">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="title, date, body"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="date">
        <p class="date"><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Note Body Stylesheet

Save this as `./ArbitraryFolder/XSL/notes/note-body.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <p class="notebody"><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Schema

The last file required is the schema; save this as `./schemas/notes/notes.xsd`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="note">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="title" type="xs:token"/>
                <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
                <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

## Building

This section details how to build the test application.

### Libraries

You will need Saxon 9 (for XSLT2.0 documents), Xerces, Xalan, and the Resolver API:

```
jaxen-1.1.6.jar
resolver.jar
saxon9he.jar
serializer.jar
xalan.jar
xercesImpl.jar
xml-apis.jar
xsltc.jar
```

### Scripts

Save as `./build.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
javac -d bin -cp .:lib/* src/TestXSD.java
```

Save as `./run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp .:bin:lib/* src.TestXSD Tests/note-to-html.xsl $1
```

### Compile

Use the `./build.sh` to compile the code.

## Run Output

Run using:

```
./run.sh filename.xml
```

### Good Test

Test that the good note passes validation:

```
./run.sh Tests/good-note2.xml
```

No errors.

### Bad Test

Test that the bad note's date does not pass validation:

```
./run.sh Tests/bad-note1.xml
```

As expected, this produces the desired error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '20140830' is not a valid value for 'date'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.finishNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.DOMValidatorHelper.validate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:124)
    at src.TestXSD.main(TestXSD.java:103)
```